# Request about description regarding cpuinfo

Tags: cpuinfo

Hi we all know that `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will provide us , but my request is i want to know the description about all the fields over there . I am giving you my PC information here. I think its not off topic and this is a helpful post.

```
raja@badfox:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 6
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 6
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est cid cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5983.43
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 6
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 6
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est cid cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5983.51
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

raja@badfox:~$
```

I know some of them like cpu type and core etc.  , but mention the description for all .

Comment: I believe this question would be better placed in SuperUser.

Comment: @EliahKagan I was simply thinking that this question is too general for this site. It has nothing specific to Ubuntu about it. I took it as a general hardware question. The information in /proc/cpuinfo is about the processor as a piece of hardware. It is not in any way OS dependent. In any case, if the more experienced users of askubuntu, such as yourself, feel it is on topic, then I am sure they are right.

Comment: @terdon Well, there are lots of questions that apply equally well to other distributions (even to *all* GNU/Linux systems) that are considered on-topic here, such as [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/151615/22949) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/147080/22949). Questions that are *totally* about hardware *are* considered off-topic...but once they are about using Ubuntu to get information about or troubleshoot the hardware, then they're on-topic (like [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/38566/22949)). You may want to post on meta to ask (or express a position) about this.

Comment: I'ld file a bug against the proc man-pages.  That way it can be sent upstream...instead of posting a question on AU.

Comment: Hi, this is overly broad. Ask Ubuntu is for specific, concrete question that have specific, concrete answers. What you're looking for is more like a manual, guide, and set of Wikipedia articles. Iake a look here: http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, This Is a Community Wiki, so Everyone fill in the information that you know, and we can make this a general answer. We can start with the description of the flags.

Information from http://www.sungju.org/?p=519 :

> **fpu** Onboard (x87) Floating Point Unit
>   **vme** Virtual Mode Extension
>   **de** Debugging Extensions
>   **pse** Page Size Extensions
>       **tsc** Time Stamp Counter: support for RDTSC and WRTSC instructions
>       **msr** Model-Specific Registers
>       **pae** Physical Address Extensions: ability to access 64GB of memory; only 4GB can be accessed at a time though
>       **mce** Machine Check Architecture
>       **cx8** CMPXCHG8 instruction
>       **apic** Onboard Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller
>       **sep** Sysenter/Sysexit Instructions; SYSENTER is used for jumps to kernel memory during system calls, and SYSEXIT is used for jumps back to the user code
>    **mtrr** Memory Type Range Registers
>    **pge** Page Global Enable
>    **mca** Machine Check Architecture
>    **cmov** CMOV instruction
>    **pat** Page Attribute Table
>    **pse36** 36-bit Page Size Extensions: allows to map 4 MB pages into the first 64GB RAM, used with PSE.
>    **pn** Processor Serial-Number; only available on Pentium 3
>    **clflush** CLFLUSH instruction
>    **dtes** Debug Trace Store
>    **acpi** ACPI via MSR
>    **mmx** MultiMedia Extension
>    **fxsr** FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions
>    **sse** Streaming SIMD Extensions. Single instruction multiple data. Lets you do a bunch of the same operation on different pieces of input in a single clock tick.
>    **sse2** Streaming SIMD Extensions-2. More of the same.
>    **selfsnoop** CPU self snoop
>    **acc** Automatic Clock Control
>    **IA64** IA-64 processor Itanium.
>    **ht** HyperThreading. Introduces an imaginary second processor that doesn’t do much but lets you run threads in the same process a bit quicker.
>    **nx** No Execute bit. Prevents arbitrary code running via buffer overflows.
>    **pni** Prescott New Instructions aka. SSE3
>    **vmx** Intel Vanderpool hardware virtualization technology
>   **svm** AMD “Pacifica” hardware virtualization technology
>   **lm** “Long Mode,” which means the chip supports the AMD64 instruction set
>   **tm** “Thermal Monitor” Thermal throttling with IDLE instructions. Usually hardware controlled in response to CPU temperature.
>   **tm2** “Thermal Monitor 2″ Decrease speed by reducing multipler and vcore.
>   **est** “Enhanced SpeedStep”

processor   : 0 -

vendor_id   : GenuineIntel -  The vendor id is "GenuineIntel" this tells you that your processor is Intel.

cpu family  : 15 -

model       : 6 -

model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz - The model name of the processor, you have a Pentium D that is the 3Ghz model

stepping    : 5 -

cpu MHz     : 2400.000 -  The Mhz of your processor.

cache size  : 2048 KB - how much cache your processor has

physical id : 0 -

siblings    : 2 -

core id     : 0 -

cpu cores   : 2 -

apicid      : 0 -

initial apicid  : 0 -

fdiv_bug    : no -

hlt_bug     : no -

f00f_bug    : no -

coma_bug    : no -

fpu     : yes -

fpu_exception   : yes -

cpuid level : 6 -

wp      : yes -

flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est cid cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm -

bogomips    : 5983.43 -

clflush size    : 64 -

cache_alignment : 128 -

address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual -

power management: -